# How to write mysql select to get daily peaks

Tags: mysql, timestamp, max

I have 'table' where i store 'rate' values every 30 minutes ('date' field). I want to get each day maximums (peaks). How can I select with one mysql request? Thanx...

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT MAX(rate) FROM 'table' GROUP BY DAY(date)
```

Should work for you :)

Comment: Thx, but this select will show only one highest max value. I need to show one max value per day. Per week it must be 7 max values (eatch day one peak). :( How to do this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. I tested a query like this on my own code and got exactly what you seemed to ask for: get the daily peak of a certain value. Could you provide a small dataset and a small example of what you are expecting as a result?

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of help!

Answer (score 0):

If the date field is a Unix timestamp, try:

```
SELECT time, MAX(data) FROM table GROUP BY DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(time))
```